# Can I input all the command at once?

Tags: java, input, command

I implemented a java program with some methods. Next I created a main class which will call the related method by entering a word.

for example:

```
Enter {A|B|C|D|E} to call method. A=method one B = method two...etc
A<--this is the user input
Enter Number:<--the first Scanner input of method A
123<--Input 1
Enter words:<-- the second Scanner input of method A
ABC<--Input 2

123ABC<--The output method A

Enter {A|B|C|D|E} to call method. A=method one B = method two...etc
B<--this is the user input
Enter Number 1:<--the first Scanner input of method B
100<--Input 1
Enter Number 2:<-- the second Scanner input of method B
50<--Input 2

150<--The output method B

Code of Method A {
String output;
private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Number:");

String no = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter Words:");

String words = keyboard.nextLine();

//do something...
System.out.println(output);
}

Code of Main class{

private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args){
Main main = new Main();
main.run();
}
  public void run() {
    boolean running = true;

    while (running) {
        displayMenu();

        String command = keyboard.nextLine();
         String[] parts = command.split("^");

        if ("A".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
            //call method A
        } else if ("B".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
            //call method B
        } else if....etc

        System.out.println();
    }
```

what I want is input
A
123 , ABC
B
100,50 at once
then the system will print the output of method A (123ABC) and B (150) for me.

What I want is input A into "keyboard", input 123 into "no" and input ABC into "words" at once

How can I do it?

Comment: I hope my answer was helpful, but you should aim to make more specific questions in the future. Your explicit question is "is it possible", to which the answer is "yes". However, we don't know what you're missing to implement a working solution, and you'll have a hard time finding someone willing to produce the whole code for you.

Comment: thanks for your answers.I changed my question so it will me more specific

Answer (score 0):

As long as your don't close your `Scanner` (or its underlying input stream), the yet-to-read tokens will remain accessible for later use : read two lines (or 4 tokens - the comma is one) and "B`\n`100,50" will remain.

If you're asking how to provide this kind of input, it depends on your invokation method. If executed from `bash`, I'd use the following :

```
echo """A
123 , ABC
B
100,50""" | java ...
```

If you're asking how to dynamically invoke a method from its name, check the reflection API. [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) is a good resource in my opinion, [here's a link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) to its section on retrieving and invoking methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do that.

**First:**

Instead of giving input directly in the console, first write all the data input somewhere and just copy it and paste it in the console.

---

**Second:**

You can use `hasNexLine()` and  send `EOF` through keyboard by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while(s.hasNextLine())
        {
            sb.append(s.nextLine());

        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

Provide all your input and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to stop taking input.

Comment: The First way is what I want to do. But it can not save into the input of Method. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Adonis.C I didn't understand your code in the question. Please post a valid working code. And what is **"it can not save into the input of Method. How can I fix it?"** Please provide valid working code, output you are expecting(which you did already) and output you are getting. What is `Code of Method A` and `Code of Main class`? Provide the code in the form of code. Not in the form of English. You can say there are similar methods are there. But you need to provide exact code structure.